# undefined reference to some OpenGL functions if they haven't been called in main

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, linker-errors, glew

if I define a function, for example `void draw()`, containing `glClear`, `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` (possibly the case for some other OpenGL functions as well) in a separate file to the main file, and then call `draw()` from the `main` function, there is an undefined reference error to the GL function that is used inside `draw`. The error does not occur if the same GL function is additionally called directly anywhere inside `main` (even if it's after the call to `draw()`). Also, the error does not occur with all GL functions, for example there is no error when calling `glUniform1f(1,1)`.

As an example, I have a folder that contains `main.cpp`, `draw.hpp`, `draw.cpp`, a `Makefile`, an `include` folder and a `lib` folder.

`main.cpp`:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "draw.hpp"

int main()
{
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw();
}
```

`draw.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

void draw();
```

`draw.cpp`:

```
#include "draw.hpp"

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

void draw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
a.exe: main.cpp draw.hpp draw.cpp
    g++ -c -o lib/libdraw.a draw.cpp -I./include
    g++ -o a.exe main.cpp -I./include -L./lib -lglew32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -ldraw
```

The `include` folder contains a `GL` folder with the glew headers. The `lib` folder contains the static glew library (and `libdraw.a` when that is compiled).

When calling `make` from cmd (that is `make` from MinGW-w64 if I'm not mistaken) with this configuration, everything compiles without errors, but if I remove `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` from `main`, I get the `undefined reference to 'glClear'` error on the `g++ -o a.exe main.cpp -I./include -L./lib -lglew32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -ldraw` step.

I know this code does not make much sense, it is just an example. I would like to know how I can properly fix these errors any why they occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `-ldraw` is last in the libraries.  Each library is added to the binary to sort out unresolved externals, and then offers new dependencies.  Given `-ldraw` is last, it can't add new dependencies, which get resolved.

Move -ldraw to first of libraries.

```
g++ -o a.exe main.cpp -I./include -L./lib -ldraw -lglew32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32
```